# How to store request response data concurrently

Tags: jmeter-5.0

i'm setting a test plan running this thread groups sequentially:

1. Execute request A using 10 threads, 500 loops.
2. Execute request B using 10 thread, 500 loops, and the output from step 1.

My problem is this:
On each request A, i receive an ID that i need to pass to request B.
What is the best way to store all the IDs and then use them on step 2?

At this time, i am "JSonExtracting" each ID from response and store on a CSV file to pass to step 2.
The problem is the concurrence of the treads. Some times i got empty spots on the file or concatenated strings which will produce an error on step 2.
I was not able to store this to an array variable to use on step 2.

To write the IDs to a file, i am using this code on a BeanShell Listener inside my threadGroup. I strongly believe this is not the most correct way to do it.

```
    f = new FileOutputStream("${DocumentIdsFile}", true);
    p = new PrintStream(f); 
    p.println("${DocumentId}");

    p.close();
    f.close();

    log.info("Id: ${Id}");
```

How can i solve this concurrence problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you receive an ID at the request A, just use it in request B, passing it throug variable:

1. Parse ID value in **request A** response using one of the [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) to store it in variable, for example `"ID"`.
2. Use it's value in your **request B** as a parametr:

   `GET https://myserver.com/myapp/getSomethig/${ID}`

Comment: Thanks but with you suggestion i only store 1 ID. i need to store all 500 ids for all 10 threads before go to step 2. Can i store to an array  variable? if yes, how?